# Using a standalone licence for SOLIDWORKS is not supported on this virtual environment. You must use a SolidNetwork License (SNL)

Tags: virtual-machines, virtualbox

I'm using Linux Mint 20.1, kernel 5.4.0 on a Ryzen 5600x with 16gb of ram.

Using VitualBox 6.1 and trying to install SolidWorks 2021 and found the message in the title when adding my license and not being able to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I found was using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

__get_random_string () {

    openssl rand -hex "${1}" | cut -c "1-${1}"

}

    __my_vm='Win'

VBoxManage setextradata "${__my_vm}" "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/DmiBIOSVendor" "American Megatrends Inc"
VBoxManage setextradata "${__my_vm}" "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/DmiBIOSVersion" "2.1.0"
VBoxManage setextradata "${__my_vm}" "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/DmiSystemVendor" "ASUSTek Computer"
VBoxManage setextradata "${__my_vm}" "VBoxInternal/Devices/pcbios/0/Config/DmiSystemSerial" "$(__get_random_string 9)"
VBoxManage setextradata "${__my_vm}" "VBoxInternal/Devices/ahci/0/Config/Port0/SerialNumber" "$(__get_random_string 20)"
VBoxManage setextradata "${__my_vm}" "VBoxInternal/Devices/ahci/0/Config/Port0/FirmwareRevision" "$(__get_random_string 8)"
VBoxManage setextradata "${__my_vm}" "VBoxInternal/Devices/ahci/0/Config/Port0/ModelNumber" "SEAGATE ST3750525AS"

exit
```

And re-lauching the vm

Comment: Sorry, where do you put this script?